# padding-left padding-right on <a> tag causes padding top and bottom

Tags: html, css

Having 3px padding on left and right of an `<a>` tag causes padding on top and bottom. See example here...(but with this jsfiddle, I only repro'd the padding on the bottom, not on the top).

```
#xyz {
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asok1421/AjnsB/7/

What's going on?

Comment: when I hover I don't see on the bottom nor on the top any padding?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It does look like #xyz is a `<div>`, not an `<a>`. But yeah, I don't see any difference either.

Comment: sorry, guys. i fixed the jsfiddle. i had the id on the wrong element. check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any padding on the top or bottom. But if this helps you:

```
#xyz{
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
}
```

padding: top right bottom left; I updated it with that and it was just fine. If you have any other concerns just ask. padding: 100px; would default to 100px on all sides.

Comment: zero values dont need a unit: `padding: 0 3px 0 3px;` even better, use shorthand: `padding: 0 3px;`

Comment: I fixed the jsfiddle to demonstrate the odd behavior.